# A succinct version of permanent that is $EXP$-complete

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, complexity-classes, permanent, succinct, examples

Succinct version of permanent is $NEXP$-hard (https://eccc.weizmann.ac.il/report/2012/086/) and so unlikely to be $EXP$-complete.

Permanent mod $2$ is in $\oplus L$ and so succinct version is unlikely to be $EXP$-complete.

> Is there a natural problem related to permanent that is $EXP$-complete?